# What are the chances of Random.NextDouble being exactly 0?

Tags: c#, .net, random

The documentation of `Random.NextDouble()`:

> Returns a random floating-point number that is greater than or equal to 0.0, and less than 1.0.

So, it can be exactly 0. But what are the chances for that?

```cs
var random = new Random();
var x = random.NextDouble()
if(x == 0){
    // probability for this?
}
```

It would be easy to calculate the probability for `Random.Next()` being 0, but I have no idea how to do it in this case...

Comment: It's 1 percent. But it might not be exactly `0.0` as the nature of the floating points. You may need to have a tolerance. What is preventing you to use integer values instead?

Comment: Assuming that the random generator is uniform, the probability should be the same as for any other number, i.e. `1/(number of possible values)`. If you round up the results to 2 decimals (0.00-1.00), it would be `1/100 = 1%`

Comment: @Eldar: No, it's *really* not 1%. Run the code a million times, and I think it's extremely unlikely that you'll find even a single value of exactly 0. As adnan_e says, it might be about 1% *if you round to 2dp*, but without rounding the chances are very, very small.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes I was getting there :)

Comment: Actually, I'll revise my "round to 2dp" part - if you round to 2dp, it's only about 0.5%, because anything 0.005 or over will be rounded up to 0.01. This is consistent with the testing I've just done.

Comment: To make it clear: I'm aware that you usually compare doubles with tolerance (a delta). But imagine, you don't want the random double to be exactly 0 (e.g. because you divide some other number through it)... That's why I'm interested in the probability.

Comment: If you make your check like this : `x < 0.1` it will approximate to 0.1. Check [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z7InpO)

Comment: Given that the result will never be 1.0, could you not just subtract the random value from 1.0 and use the result, which will never be 0.0?

Comment: *"you don't want the random double to be exactly 0 (e.g. because you divide some other number through it)..."* - The chances are > 0.0%. This is fair enough to make your application crash in case the operation is a division and the generated value is the divisor. You *must* check the result to handle a value of 0 (e.g., by generating a new number or by using something like `Math.Max` to coerce it).

Comment: @BionicCode I know. I'm not looking for a justification to ignore the fact that it can be 0. I'm interested in the probability and maybe even how to calculate it.

Comment: @ndsvw: It's *extremely* unlikely, but not impossible. (I wrote a quick program to check a billion iterations - running it a few times, it spotted just a single value of 0.0.) Beyond "very rare, but not impossible" does the exact probability really matter?

Comment: RandomDouble() starts with a [random integer](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,94) in the range 0..int.MaxValue-1.  The odds for 0 are therefore 100% * 1/2147483646 = 4.66E-8 %.  Or in other words, on average you'd have to loop two billion times to get one zero.

Comment: @JonSkeet I mean... It would have been interesting to know... :)

Comment: @HansPassant: That assumes that exactly one seed value will give you a value of 0 immediately, and doesn't take account of anything else about the internals. I think it *entirely* possible that the probability isn't exactly uniform like that.

Comment: Maybe the question is more about IEEE 754... If one knows how many numbers there are between 0 inclusive and 1 exclusive (according to IEEE 754), it would be possible to answer the 'probability' question, because 0 is one of all of them. So, the probability = 1 / (number of possible numbers between 0 inclusive and 1 exclusive according to IEEE 754)

Comment: Note that the implementation of `Random` is different for newer versions of .NET, where [it uses 64-bit values rather than 32-bit values](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Random.Xoshiro256StarStarImpl.cs,82d6ed1c69a1ed98) to generate random numbers. This means that the probability of generating exactly 0 using `NextDouble()` changes wildly between .NET versions.

Comment: Looking at the .NET 6 implementation it uses 53 bits of a random 64 bit number. Only one of those permutations of 53 bits generates a zero double, so the actual probability of a zero double is 1/(2^53) = `~1.11e-16` (note: That's a probability, not a % chance. I refuse to use % for probabilities...)

Comment: The random generation when duplicates are allowed has a probability of P%=A/n*100, where A is the number of opportunities and n is the count of possible values. You want a single value, therefore A=1. Given that double has a precision of 15, you have 10^15 numbers between [0..1), (include 0 but 1). Then you get n=10^15. It's P%=1/(10^15)*100. Which gives a very very very small number. If you don't allow to generate duplicates, then with each generation the chances will increase. Like after generating n-1 numbers (10^15-1), you have 1 number left (n=1). The probability is now 100% (1/1*100).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Is anyone here interested in posting an answer I could accept?

Comment: I'm actually having too much fun pointing out all the ways the answers the bounties are attracting are wrong to post anything myself.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in comments, it depends on internal implementation of `NextDouble`. In "old" .NET Framework, and in modern .NET up to version 5, it looks like [this](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,195):

```
protected virtual double Sample() {
    return (InternalSample()*(1.0/MBIG));
}
```

`InternalSample` returns integer in 0 to `Int32.MaxValue` range, 0 included, `int.MaxValue` excluded. We can assume that the distribution of `InternalSample` is uniform (in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=net-7.0) for `Next` method, which just calls `InternalSample`, there are clues that it is, and it seems there is no reason to use non-uniform distribution in general-purpose RNG for integers). That means every number is equally likely. Then, we have 2,147,483,647  numbers in distribution, and the probability to draw 0 is 1 / 2,147,483,647.

In modern .NET 6+ there are two implementations. First is used when you provide explicit seed value to `Random` constructor. This implementation is the same as above, and is used for compatibility reasons - so that old code relying on the seed value to produce deterministic results will not break while moving to the new .NET version.

Second implementation is a new one and is used when you do NOT pass seed into `Random` constructor. [Source code](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Random.Xoshiro256StarStarImpl.cs,19):

```
public override double NextDouble() =>
    // As described in http://prng.di.unimi.it/:
    // "A standard double (64-bit) floating-point number in IEEE floating point format has 52 bits of significand,
    //  plus an implicit bit at the left of the significand. Thus, the representation can actually store numbers with
    //  53 significant binary digits. Because of this fact, in C99 a 64-bit unsigned integer x should be converted to
    //  a 64-bit double using the expression
    //  (x >> 11) * 0x1.0p-53"
    (NextUInt64() >> 11) * (1.0 / (1ul << 53));
```

We first obtain random 64-bit unsigned integer. Now, we could multiply it by 1 / 2^64 to obtain `double` in 0..1 range, but that would make the resulting distribution biased. `double` is represented by 53-bit mantissa (52 bits are explicit and one is implicit) ,exponent and sign. For all integer values exponent is the same, so that leaves us with 53 bits to represent integer values. But we have 64-bit integer here. This means integer values less than 2^53 can be represented exactly by `double` but bigger integers can not. For example:

```
ulong l1 = 1ul << 53;
ulong l2 = l1 + 1;
double d1 = l1;
double d2 = l2;
Console.WriteLine(d1 == d2);
```

Prints "true", so two different integers map to the same `double` value. That means if we just multiply our 64-bit integer by 1 / 2^64 - we'll get a biased non-uniform distribution, because many integers bigger than 2^53-1 will map to the same values.

So instead, we throw away 11 bits, and multiply the result by 1 / 2^53 to get uniform distibution in 0..1 range. The probability to get 0 is then 1 / 2^53 (1 / 9,007,199,254,740,992). This implementation is better than the old one, because is provides much more different doubles in 0 .. 1 range (2^53 compared to 2^32 in old one).

You also asked in comments:

> If one knows how many numbers there are between 0 inclusive and 1
> exclusive (according to IEEE 754), it would be possible to answer the
> 'probability' question, because 0 is one of all of them

That's not so. There are actually more than 2^53 representable numbers between 0..1 in IEEE 754. We have 52 bits of mantissa, then we have 11 bits of exponent, half of which is for negative exponents. Almost all negative exponents (rougly half of that 11 bit range) combined with mantissa gives us distinct value in 0..1 range.

Why we can't use full 0..1 range which IEEE allows us to generate random number? Because this range is not uniform (like the full double range is not uniform itself). For example there are more representable numbers in 0 .. 0.5 range than in 0.5 .. 1 range.